# I have an error about using class and objects

Tags: java, class, object

```
public final class Set implements ASet {
Integer[] NewSet;

    public void Set() {
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(int value) {
        for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
            if (this.NewSet[i] == value) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                this.NewSet[9] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void union(ASet set) {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            this.insert(set.NewSet[j]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int[] show() {
        return Array.from(this.NewSet);
    }
}
```

I want to insert the interger.
When I compile it, there is an error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        this.insert(set.NewSet[j]);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable NewSet
  location: variable set of type ASet
```

And I want to return the elements of the object as an array by show() method, but there is another error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    return Array.from(this.NewSet);
                ^
  symbol:   method from(Integer[])
  location: class Array
```

Comment: `NewSet` is defined in the `Set` class, not the `ASet` class. The compiler doesn't know if all implementations of `ASet` would have that field (not that you can define member variables in interfaces anyway).

Comment: It's unlikely that the interface `ASet` has defined a variable (constant) called `NewSet` too. Maybe you wanted to declare `set` as `Set` instead?

Comment: I would recommend against naming a class "Set" which is one of the standard Collections interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` only works in arrays, not in `Set` (also `Set` is not ordered, there is no concept of first or second element, if you need order use `SortedSet`). You can iterate over a set to get its values.